# Fetch new data from SQL in python every few seconds

Tags: python, sql

I want to make a python script that consistently checks the Mysql database and prints out new updated records every few seconds.

```
import time
sql_conn = connectSQLServer('ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server', 'D\SQLEXPRESS', 'display')

mycursor = sql_conn.cursor()

a = 0
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        a=a+1
        print(a)
        sql = "SELECT id, val FROM dbo.LiveStatsFromSQLServer"    
        mycursor.execute(sql)

        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

        for x in myresult:
            print(x)


    except Exception as error:
        print("Nothing in database\n")
        print(error)
sql_conn.commit()
```

Expected output:
The columns are (id, value)

```
1second
(1625, 3)
(1626, 0)
(1627, 10)
2second
(1625, 3)
(1626, 0)
(1627, 10)
3second
(1625, 3)
(1626, 0)
(1627, 10)
(1628,20)
```

Comment: There's no question here - what's the problem?

Comment: The code is generating all the outputs, where I want new sql outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your records appear to start with an auto-incrementing identifier, you could do:

```
sql = "SELECT id, val FROM dbo.LiveStatsFromSQLServer WHERE id > %s"
mycursor.execute(sql, prev_id)
```

And after the `print(x)` just add something like `prev_id = x[0]`:

```
    for x in myresult:
        print(x)
        prev_id = x[0]
```

Note: I don't know what the actual first column of your result is called, just replace `id` with the actual column name in the script if you want to `select *` instead of naming the columns (and assuming there's 2).

Comment: Hi Grismar, thank for your quick reply, i got a error saying that prev_id is not defined

Comment: You'll need to initialise `prev_id` before the loop starts, e.g. `prev_id = 0`, to something less than the smallest possible identifier. (could be 0, could be -1, could be the maximum negative integer, but 0 is most likely - have a look at your database to decide what a sensible start value is)